FCM push notification approach
I've successfully set up push notifications using Spring and React. However, since it's my first time with FCM, I have a few questions to clarify. Here's the scenario: When a user books a room or house, the owner should receive a push notification on their device.
Here's my planned approach:

Capture and store the device token every time a user signs up or signs in, either in the user table or a new table for handling multiple devices.
When a user books a room, retrieve their device token(s) from the server and send the notification to the device.

Questions:

Is this the best approach?
How do I handle situations where the user is still logged in on a device but the push notification should not be sent (e.g., when they log out)? Do I verify their session serverside?


FCM does not know or care about if a user is logged in or not. FCM only cares about doing what its suppose to do. If you do not wan to show the user a notification from FCM when they are logged out then you need to either implement your own logic when the app gets the notification from the FCM service or invalidate the FCM token upon logout and the app wont get anything.

In my point of view, your case requires server to handle the push notification.

When login or logout, send the state and token so that the server knows whether the user is logged in or logged out.
The android client sends the booked room or house id to the server.
The server verifies whether the room owner is logged in.
If the owner is logged in, the server should trigger the notification.

The android client does not need to know other users token if you have backend service.

The android client just needs to tell the server that there's a booking request.
Then the server that has recorded the the room owner FCM token can push notification telling the room owner about the request.
